# python performance dealing with binary files

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a [YCbCr-file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) 
from 8 bpp to 10 bpp.

My best approach so far is still order of magnitude slower
than the most basic naive C implementation.

Naive approach in C, runs in about 8s. Making the code to
work on chunks instead, drops the time to well under 1s.

I'm curious about what kind of performance it's possible to get
from standard python dealing with binary files. Example file is
in [CIF-resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Format) and is "small" in comparison to content in 1080p.
Feel free to add numpy-suggestions as well although I'm mainly interested
in standard python.

The test-file can be downloaded from

```
http://trace.eas.asu.edu/yuv/foreman/foreman_cif.7z
```

`sha1sum` for correct 10-bit output is

```
c511dabc793383f7fd0ed69b4bb9b9f89ef73b84
```

python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import array

f_in = 'foreman_cif.yuv'
f_out = 'py_10bpp.yuv'

def bytesfromfile(f):
    while True:
        raw = array.array('B')
        raw.fromstring(f.read(8192))
        if not raw:
            break
        yield raw

with open(f_in, 'rb') as fd_in, \
        open(f_out, 'wb') as fd_out:

    for byte in bytesfromfile(fd_in):
        data = []
        for i in byte:
            i <<= 2
            data.append(i & 0xff)
            data.append((i >> 8) & 0xff)

        fd_out.write(array.array('B', data).tostring())
```

Naive C-dito:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int c;
    int d[2];

    FILE* fd_in;
    FILE* fd_out;

    fd_in = fopen("foreman_cif.yuv", "rb");
    fd_out = fopen("c_10bpp.yuv", "wb");

    while((c = fgetc(fd_in)) != EOF) {
        c <<= 2;
        d[0] = c & 0xff;
        d[1] = (c >> 8) & 0xff;

        fwrite(&d[0], 1, 1, fd_out);
        fwrite(&d[1], 1, 1, fd_out);
    }

    fclose(fd_in);
    fclose(fd_out);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, running this code takes me 33 s in CPython and (unmodified) 7 s in PyPy, and ~3 s in C.

Comment: same ballpark here: CPython ~20s and ~2.5 in C when compiled with `-O2`. First did the measurements without the power-cord to my laptop which caused my cores to run @ 800MHz. "order of magnitude" comes from this. with power-cord connected and cores running @2.2GHz I get the numbers above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code from the question takes `25` seconds on my machine, `numpy` -- `0.37` seconds:

```
import numpy as np

a_in = np.memmap('foreman_cif.yuv', mode='readonly')
a_out = np.memmap('py_10bpp.yuv', mode='write', shape=2*len(a_in))
a_out[::2] = a_in << 2
a_out[1::2] = a_in >> 6
```

`cython` -- `0.20` seconds:

```
from functools import partial

import pyximport; pyximport.install() # pip install cython
from bpp8to10 import convert # bpp8to10.pyx

f_in = 'foreman_cif.yuv'
f_out = 'py_10bpp.yuv'

def main():
    with open(f_in, 'rb') as fd_in, open(f_out, 'wb') as fd_out:
        for chunk in iter(partial(fd_in.read, 8192), b''):
            fd_out.write(convert(chunk))
main()
```

Where `bpp8to10.pyx`:

```
from cpython.bytes cimport PyBytes_FromStringAndSize

def convert(bytes chunk not None):
    cdef:
        bytes data = PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(NULL, len(chunk)*2)
        char* buf = data # no copy
        Py_ssize_t j = 0
        unsigned char c
    for c in chunk:
        buf[j] = (c << 2) 
        buf[j + 1] = (c >> 6)
        j += 2
    return data
```

The main speedup in pure CPython version is from moving the code from the module level into a function (`main()`) -- `6.7` seconds (2 CPUs):

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool

f_in = 'foreman_cif.yuv'
f_out = 'py_10bpp.yuv'

def convert(chunk):
    data = bytearray() # [] -> bytearray(): 17 -> 15 seconds
    data_append = data.append # 15 -> 12  seconds
    for b in bytearray(chunk): # on Python 3: `for b in chunk:`
        data_append((b << 2) & 0xff)
        data_append((b >> 8) & 0xff)
    return data

def main(): # put in main(): # 25 -> 17 seconds
    pool = Pool(processes=2) # 12 -> 6.7 seconds
    with open(f_in, 'rb') as fd_in, open(f_out, 'wb') as fd_out:
        for data in pool.imap(convert, iter(partial(fd_in.read, 8192), b'')):
            fd_out.write(data)
main()
```

`pypy` -- `1.6` seconds:

```
f_in = 'foreman_cif.yuv'
f_out = 'py_10bpp.yuv'

def convert(chunk):
    data = bytearray() # 1.6 -> 1.5 seconds for preallocated data
    for b in bytearray(chunk): 
        data.append((b << 2) & 0xff)
        data.append((b >> 6) & 0xff)
    return data

with open(f_in, 'rb') as fd_in, open(f_out, 'wb') as fd_out:
    while True:
        chunk = fd_in.read(8192)
        if not chunk:
            break
        fd_out.write(convert(chunk))
```

Comment: This looks very promising. I'm impressed!. Thank you.