# optimize python nested loops for YUV2RGB conversion

Tags: python, optimization

We just derived the YUV2RGB algorithm from Hikvision.  However for our 720H x 1280W screen resolution python conversion it takes too long (15 seconds) for 720x1280=921,600 rounds of calculations for 1 single RGB frame.  Any one knows how to optimized the following 2 large nested loop?  The YUV2RGB algorithm is:

def YUV2RGB (Y1, U1, V1, dwHeight, dwWidth):  # function call

```
RGB1 = np.zeros(dwHeight * dwWidth * 3, dtype=np.uint8)  # create 1 dimensional empty np array with 720x1280x3

for i in range (0, dwHeight):    #0-720
    for j in range (0, dwWidth): #0-1280 

        # print "cv"

        Y = Y1[i * dwWidth + j]; 
        U = U1[(i / 2) * (dwWidth / 2) + (j / 2)]; 
        V = V1[(i / 2) * (dwWidth / 2) + (j / 2)];

        R = Y + (U - 128) + (((U - 128) * 103) >> 8); 
        G = Y - (((V - 128) * 88) >> 8) - (((U - 128) * 183) >> 8); 
        B = Y + (V - 128) + (((V - 128) * 198) >> 8);

        R = max(0, min(255, R)); 
        G = max(0, min(255, G)); 
        B = max(0, min(255, B));

        RGB1[3 * (i * dwWidth + j)] = B; 
        RGB1[3 * (i * dwWidth + j) + 1] = G; 
        RGB1[3 * (i * dwWidth + j) + 2] = R; 

RGB = np.reshape(RGB1, (dwHeight, dwWidth, 3))

print ("rgb.shape:")
print RGB.shape

return RGB
```

"for i in range (0, dwHeight):    #0-720
        for j in range (0, dwWidth): #0-1280 "

is too large.  Any way to optimize this.  Thanks.

Matthew

Comment: May not be what you're looking for -- there are probably ways to obfuscate the algorithm to please numpy -- but I can imagine that just running this code on PyPy is maybe 50 times faster than CPython.

Comment: actually vectorized numpy operations may even [simplify the code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15911233/4279) but you could use [Cython](http://cython.org) or [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) to keep the code almost the same.