# Python: convert a byte to binary and shift its bits?

Tags: python, binary

I want to convert an encoding to another encoding in Python for a school project. However, the encoding I am translating from will add a padding to its encoding on the first bit.

How do I shift an binary number sequence to the left by one, so that it goes from:

00000001 11001100 01010101 and so on

to

00000011 10011000 10101010 and so on

so the end result's lowest bit will be the former's highest bit number?

Comment: how many bytes does it have? is it 3 or was that just an example?

Comment: At some point you'll need to test the leftmost bit before doing a left shift. You can optimize how often you'll need to do that by eg. packing multiple bytes into a larger int (check the `struct` module).

Comment: just 3 is an example, but its a continuously growing number. As its actually data transmitted from somewhere and its needs to be converted out to be printed in a different format.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can convert the string to one big integer and then do the left-shift (and then convert the big integer back into a string):

```
large_int = bytes2int(mystring)
large_int <<= 1
mystring = int2bytes(large_int)
```

using e.g. this simplistic implementation:

```
def bytes2int(str):
    res = ord(str[0])
    for ch in str[1:]:
        res <<= 8
        res |= ord(ch)
    return res

def int2bytes(n):
    res = []
    while n:
        ch = n & 0b11111111
        res.append(chr(ch))
        n >>= 8
    return ''.join(reversed(res))

bytes = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv'
assert int2bytes(bytes2int(bytes)) == bytes
```

Comment: It is inefficient to process one byte at a time. You could use `int.from_bytes()`, `int.to_bytes()` methods on Python 3 and [`binascii.unhexlify` on Python 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28524760/4279). See also, [Convert Binary to ASCII and vice versa (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7396849/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian you're absolutely correct, hence the note about 'simplistic' implementation (the OP is doing binary encoding work, so I figured a bit-fiddling example could be interesting).

Comment: If you want to show byte at a time operation; you could [use `bytearray()` that is Python 2/3, Pypy compatible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15916760/4279)

Comment: Is anyone actually using Python 3/Pypy? <wink>

Comment: I just tested `bytearray` performance on Python 2.7.10 (using the example at the bottom of http://www.dotnetperls.com/bytes), and it seems like it is almost 10% slower than a plain list.  FWIW, I would expect PyPy to be able to optimize the functions in the answer without any problems (Cython makes it about twice as fast with very few changes).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `<<` operator to left shift, and conversely `>>` will right shift

```
>>> x = 7485254
>>> bin(x)
'0b11100100011011101000110'
>>> bin(x << 1)
'0b111001000110111010001100'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [bitstring](http://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/) library which allows for bitwise operations on arbitrarily long bitstrings e.g. to import and shift your binary number:

```
>>> import bitstring
>>> bitstring.BitArray(bin='0b11100100011011101000110') << 1
BitArray('0b11001000110111010001100')
```